# Keep input mask showing while filling the input

Tags: javascript, css

When a user focuses on an input I want to show them the input mask like this

[image]

And when they start typing I want the mash still be showing like this

[image]

But I have no idea how to implement this. I tried to find something similar on codepen or other websites. But I only found solutions where the mask disappers when a user starts typing.

As I can see the mask is not a part of the typed number (I mean the mask is not concatenated to the input text). Also the mask disappears on blur

[image]

How can I implement this with pure JavaScript? Maybe provide a link to some article/video with explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres is a proposal solution using a text mask: https://codepen.io/aSH-uncover/pen/VwXEvLb

The idea is to split the input in several chuncks of 2 digits so that we can apply a mask easily on each splitted part.
This raises some tricky eventing management depending how you want the control to behave ; what I propose here is only an example, surely not some production ready code ;)

First an HTML file with a minimal scenario (4 digit phone number :D)

```
<div>
  <label>Phone number</label>
</div>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='group'>
    <input id='input1' maxlength ='2' placeholder='01' />
    <label id='mask1' class='mask' />
  </div>
  <div class='group'>
    <input id='input2' maxlength ='2' placeholder='23' />
    <label id='mask2' class='mask' />
  </div>
</div>
```

Then some styling

```
.group {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
}
input {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.mask {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0%;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-bottom-color: grey;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}
```

Finaly pure javascript eventing

```
const input1 = document.querySelector('#input1');
const mask1 = document.querySelector('#mask1');
const input2 = document.querySelector('#input2');
const mask2 = document.querySelector('#mask2');

let nextBackspaceSuppr = false

input1.addEventListener('keyup', onUp1);
input1.addEventListener('focus', onFocus1);
input2.addEventListener('keydown', onDown2);
input2.addEventListener('keyup', onUp2);
input2.addEventListener('focus', onFocus2);

function onUp1 (oEvent) {
  switch (oEvent.target.value.length) {
    case 0: {
      mask1.style.width = '0%'
      input2.placeholder = '23'
      mask2.style.width = '100%'
      break;
    }
    case 1: {
      input2.placeholder = ''
      mask1.style.width = '50%'
      mask2.style.width = '100%'
      break;
    }
    default: {
      input2.placeholder = ''
      mask1.style.width = '0%'
      mask2.style.width = '100%'
      input2.focus()
      break;
    }
  }
}

function onFocus1 (oEvent) {
  if (input1.value.length > 1) {
    input2.focus()
  }
}

function onDown2 (oEvent) {
  if (oEvent.target.value.length === 0 && oEvent.key === 'Backspace') {
    nextBackspaceSuppr = true
  }
}

function onUp2 (oEvent) {
  switch (oEvent.target.value.length) {
    case 0: {
      mask2.style.width = '100%'
      if (oEvent.key === 'Backspace') {
        if (nextBackspaceSuppr) {
          input1.value = input1.value.substr(0, 1)  
        }
        input1.focus()
      }
      break;
    }
    case 1: {
      mask2.style.width = '50%'
      break;
    }
    default: {
      mask2.style.width = '0%'
      input2.focus()
      break;
    }
  }
  nextBackspaceSuppr = false
}

function onFocus2 (oEvent) {
  if (input1.value.length < 2) {
    input1.focus()
  }
}
```

Comment: wow! Thank you. But what if I want to use some characters (like ##-##) instead of underlines? As far as I understand you use border bottom as a mask. But what about using characters in a mask?

Comment: U can play on other properties than the border ; I updated the code pen so that it uses text content instead but even there this is probably not what you want in the end, up to you to build the exact rendering you need if you follow this approach ;)

Answer (score 0):

why did you put it in css catagory?

```
document.getElementById("body").style.position =  "fixed";
   const canvass = document.getElementById('canvas');
   const ctx = canvass.getContext('2d')
   var number = "2"
   var pressed =0
   //pressed should be 1 if it is pressed
   var thefullnum=number+"2302"
   if(!pressed){
    ctx.globalAlpha= 0.3;
    ctx.fillText(thefullnum,50,50);
    ctx.globalAlpha= 1;
    ctx.fillText(number,50,50);}else{
    //when its pressed
    ctx.fillText("__-__-__",50,50);
   
    ctx.fillStyle="white"
    ctx.fillRect(number.length,20,50,50)
    ctx.fillStyle="black"
    ctx.fillText(number,50,50);}
```